# uploading php file type with php code

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code with which I am uploading different file types onto my server. Those are mostly picture files and pdf. I am trying now to upload a .php file but I am getting an error.

```
$folder      = $_POST['folder_name'];
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pdf", "php");
$temp        = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension   = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/php")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "
<div style='position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin-top:-80px;margin-left:-80px;width:300px;height:200px;'>";
        echo "<br><br><span style='font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;'>Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</span><br>";
        echo "<br><br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Back to CMS\" onclick=\"location.href='index_upload.php'\">";
    } else {
        echo "
    <div style='position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin-top:-80px;margin-    left:-80px;width:300px;height:200px;'>";
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists($folder . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " <br><br><span style='font-weight:bold;text-    decoration:underline;'>already exists</span>.
        ";
            echo "<br><br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Back to CMS\" onclick=\"location.href='index_upload.php'\">";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file(
                $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                $folder . $_FILES["file"]["name"]
            );
            echo "<br><span style='font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;'>Stored in:</span> " . $folder .
                $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            echo "<br><br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Back to CMS\" onclick=\"location.href='index_upload.php'\">";
            echo "
    </div>
    ";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "
    <div style='position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin-top:-50px;margin-left:-50px;width:200px;height:200px;'>";
    echo "<span style='font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;'>Invalid file</span>";
    echo "<br><br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Back to CMS\" onclick=\"location.href='index_upload.php'\">";
    echo "
    </div>
    ";
}
```

I am getting the last error show INVALID FILE.

Comment: Are you sure the extension is in lowercase? Make sure so that the $_FILES['file']['type'];` is correct.

Comment: So `print_r($_FILES['file'])` and see what you have there

Comment: Array ( [name] => delete_file.php [type] => application/octet-stream [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpQ0MNN6 [error] => 0 [size] => 159 ) That is what i get

Comment: your file_type check is not letting through `application/octet-stream`...

Comment: i have seen it, how could i fix it

Comment: Did you gave it a try??

Comment: I am sorry I didn't, I can not find the part that is going to solve my case

Answer (score 0):

I made this tutorial after I attempted the same task, Please have a look.

[Upload File, image or Videos](https://kartikasthana.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/upload-a-pdf-or-doc-or-a-video-in-php-5/)

1. Please indent the code, it is easy to read and find errors.
2. We have the facility to check what error has occurred and why.

   `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` gives the error code which can be decoded form the documentation.
3. I have used a file extension finfo (wwhich has to be made active by doing changes in php.ini file) which personally I feel is a better way to check the MIME type of multipart form data.
4. I have also mentioned errors because of max file upload size, execution time etc parameters which are set to some default value in php.ini and have to be changed to make this operation a success.
5. Always you can ask for any thing that confuses you or any error what comes in front after reading this.